# System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Gamer\Desktop\дз 9\1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\downloaded\'."

Tags: c#

Делаю телеграм бота, который скачивает файлы, которые отправляет пользователь.

```
string path = "downloaded\\";

if (e.Message.Type == Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.MessageType.Document)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message.Document.FileId);
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message.Document.FileName);
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message.Document.FileSize);

                DownLoad(e.Message.Document.FileId, path);
            }

static async void DownLoad(string fileId, string path)
        { 
            var file = await bot.GetFileAsync(fileId);
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
            await bot.DownloadFileAsync(file.FilePath, fs);
            fs.Close();

            fs.Dispose();
        }
```

При попытке загрузить файл, в методе Download в строке "FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);" вылезает ошибка, которая в заголовке. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: нет там у вас такой директории, создайте сначала, чтобы туда файлы сохранять

Comment: как нет если есть
https://dropmefiles.com/d0SvS

Comment: Вы что, пытаетесь прямо в папку записать, без имени файла в конце?

Comment: Кстати, Close и Dispose в случае потоков ввода-вывода являются синонимами.

Comment: О Боги, точно, имя файла, спасибо огромное!

Comment: используйте конструкцию `using`, не вызывайте Close или Dispose вручную. - https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects и познакомьтесь с методом `Path.Combine`.